# JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'autocomplete'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

 '$'(function () {$("input#txtSearch").autocomplete({

            source:'@Url.Action("GetPatients")',

            minLength:2

        });

    });

</script>
```

I'm new to jQuery and I have no idea why I'm  getting this error could someone explain and give a solution?

Comment: Have you imported jQuery and jQueryUI?

Comment: why is the first dollar in quotes?

Answer (score 0):

You mean this:

```
$(function () {

    $("input#txtSearch").autocomplete({
        source: '@Url.Action("GetPatients")',
        minLength: 2
    });

});
```

Try to work on your code indentation, it would make your code more readable and easy to detect this kind of typos